# How to extract part of the current working directory to the statusline?

Tags: regular-expression, statusline, string-manipulation

I have a lot of projects of the form:

```
/home/karl/source/project-name/further/hierarchy/...
```

I would like to extract just the `project-name` to put into my statusline.  I use `autochdir`, so I know I can create a function that calls `getcwd()` and extracts that part.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do the parsing after that point.

```
function ProjectName()
  return ???getcwd()???
endfunc

set statusline=%t\ %m%r%{ProjectName()}%{fugitive#statusline()}%=%l,%c\ [0x%B]\ %P
```

If I edit something outside that folder, I'd like to leave the project blank.  Can someone fill in the `???` for me?

Comment: `:help fnamemodify`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution might work, but I think this is a slightly cleaner and more readable version:

```
function ProjectName()
  let l:path = expand('%:p')
  return (l:path =~# '^/home/karl/source/.\+')
        \ ? substitute(l:path, '^/home/karl/source/\([^/]*\)/.*', '\1', '')
        \ : '...'
endfunction
```

Also, it seems you add the brackets `[...]` both through the function and through the statusline option. I would think this should only come through the function.

Comment: Yes, I removed the brackets from the statusline later, because I want nothing to show up when I'm outside of the source directory.  Your version also has the bonus of fixing a weird bug when I `:e /home/karl/source`.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @romainl's comment for pointing me in the right direction.  Here's my solution:

```
function ProjectName()
    if expand("%:p") =~ "^/home/karl/source/[^/]*/"
        return "[" . fnamemodify('', ':p:s?/home/karl/source/\([^/]*\)/.*?\1?') . "]"
    else
        return ""
endfunc
```